# Стриминг видеодорожки вместе с музыкой на youtube. (python)

Tags: python

Всем мир)

Подскажите как лучше реализовать данную задачу, какие библиотеки использовать и т.д

Брать данные из нескольких папок, воспроизводить их через VLC и запускать стриминговый поток через OBS на youtube.
Готовое решение не нужно просто подскажите наиболее практичные алгоритмы выполнения данной задачи.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вроде в OBS есть источник, который так и называется VLC, он вам чем-то не подходит или в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: @andreymal здравствуйте, мне это надо автоматизировать, просто надо понять как лучше это сделать)

Comment: В OBS встроен плагин Websocket, через который вы можете его контролировать

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо вам)